# Div containing a form isn't taking up the entire page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms, lightbox

I have created a lightbox link which contains a Div. Inside the Div element there is a form, however the div isn't expanding to 100% of the page body. Does anyone know why?

Here's the code:

CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <style>
  @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Londrina+Sketch);

  body {
  background-color: #C13E18;
  width: 750px;
  overflow:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
  }

.form {
width: 100%;
float: left;

}

</style>
</head>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id=bookingpage>

<div id="form"> <object type="text/html" data="http://challenge-the-box.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=frm_forms_preview&form=nb3dui</div>" style="overflow:auto;">
    </object></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: also the link can be found [here](http://www.challenge-the-box.com/booking) and click on 'click here'

Answer (score 1):

You're applying the style to a class called "form".

Your actual div doesn't have the class it has an ID of form. The hash tag is the ID selector.

**Current**

```
.form {
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
}
```

**Should be**

```
   #form {
       width: 100%;
       float: left;
    }
```

You might also have to specify 100% width for the object also:

```
#form, #form object{
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Great! Tha'ts extended it to the width of the page, however it's still forcing a overflow scroll bar for the height. Even when I add 'height: 100%'. Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't want an overflow you can do overflow:none;

Comment: Sorry I don't think that is what you want. I'll have a look when I get home. Could you provide a JSFiddle or something or a code snippet here on StackOverflow so we can see it in action. @Marc

Comment: I can't seem to get it working on JSFiddle, however the code is live [here](http://www.challenge-the-box.com/booking). Just click on the link 'click here' when the page loads to launch the lightbox frame.

Comment: any ideas yet? I'm having to hold my breath for this one

Comment: Sorry @Marc, I did have another look when I was on my lunch today. From what I've read it's the way that `iframe` are rendered. Do you have access to the iframes CSS file? If so try adding `html, body{ width: 100%; height: 100%;}` Have you thought about not using an `iframe`? If that doesn't work can you add a copy of the `iframe` HTML and CSS?

Comment: I'm sure I have access to the iframe css, however locating it is another matter... I have attempted to load the page using script this is what I did: '<script>$("#testLoad").load(http://challenge-the-box.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=frm_forms_preview&form=nb3dui);</script>' then just '<div id="testLoad"></div>' however it didn't do anything.

Comment: The issue is loading a page within a page, can you not replicate the form inside the modal?

Answer (score 0):

```
#form {
width: 100%;
float: left;

}
```

On css, any item start with dot is class, start with # is id.

Comment: thanks for noticing that! I've changed that however it's still not filling up the entire parent div vertically and has a nav scroll bar

Answer (score 0):

Your body script is incorrect.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <style>
  @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Londrina+Sketch);

  body {
  background-color: #C13E18;
  width: 750px;
  overflow:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
  }

#form {
width: 100%;
float: left;

}

</style>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id=bookingpage>
      <div id="form"> 
        <object type="text/html" data="http://challenge-the-box.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=frm_forms_preview&form=nb3dui" style="overflow:auto;">
        </object>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You placed closing div inside data url.